# What do you call a verb that requires another verb?

Tags: terminology, grammar

I know that verbs are sometimes called "transitive" and I think that means the can take a direct object.

I'm learning Mandarin and there seems to be some verbs that can only take other verbs. For example start/stop 開始／停止.

You cannot start a book, you must start TO READ the book, and you cannot start a meal, you must start TO EAT the meal. In English we can start/stop both NP and VP (stop what you're doing / stop doing that).

Is there a name for this kind of verb? It seems modal or auxiliary verbs must take other verbs, but these verbs in question don't feel very modal-like to me.

Interested in others' knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Just mentioning that both patterns amount to the same notion of a verb taking an **argument** - be this an NP object or another VP (or a PP, ...), in both cases the verb can be seen as transitive in requiring an object. However, I don't know a terminological distinction between the two cases you mentioned, plus *transitivity* is mostly used in the context of verbs taking NP or PP objects (but I think speaking of transitivity when verbs take a verbal object is not misplaced).

Comment: "Start" can be used transitively as in _Start the engine_; _I've just started a new course_ and so on. When it takes a VP as complement, it's called a catenative verb as in _He started to shout loudly_.

Comment: @BillJ I had never heard of "catenative", nice one! I'm asking if there is a term for a verb that can only take another verb or VP. It seems like your example above is more a "catenative" context, rather than a catenative verb, since it can take both. The only types of verbs I can think of that ONLY take other verbs are aux/modals, but these verbs in Mandarin are not really aux/modals.

Comment: It seems that [Compound Verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_verb#English) is the term you're looking for,.

Comment: @bytebuster I looked it over, and I'm not sure compound verbs are what is happening in this example. "The English lexicon contains a few true compound verbs, such as stirfry, kickstart and forcefeed." This seems more like two verbs that combine in a way to make a specific "compound" verb. I'm referring to a verb that can only take another VP, never an indirect object or NP.

Comment: @pixelearth Whenever a verb (or also a noun or anything else) can take different types of arguments - e.g. *stop* either used with an NP or with a VP - it is usually assumed that the word has two lexicon entries, each containing one argument structure. So it doesn't matter if such a catenative verb can also take different kinds of arguments in another context, because you can just asumme that this is a slightly different "stop" which is independent of the catenative use. Of course, this simplicication is arguable, but as far as I know this is the standard assumption being made.

Comment: It's a catenative verb, as discussed above: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb For this adjective and many others, see e.g. https://sites.google.com/site/b3fink4urself/Home/verbs and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Verb_types

Comment: @Luboš Motl Yes, but the OP is looking for the name of a class of verbs that must take a verb complement. Many catenative verbs can also be transitive verbs as well, e.g. "want".

Comment: Let me clarify @lemontree and Lubos. My interest is in language learning and education. lemontree, you mention that it is "usually assumed that the word has two lexicon entries" and that "this is the standard assumption being made." I agree completely! And it is this assumption that led me to make impossible sentences in Mandarin, since these verbs CANNOT take a NP. So my assumptions were wrong. It seems reasonable to me to "start dinner" or "start eating dinner" or "start to eat dinner", but in Mandarin these verbs MUST take another VP.

Comment: So I'm wondering if there is a category for these verbs that, as you say, can only function in a "catenative" context.

Comment: @pixelearth - I think that *every* catenative verb may be a transitive verb so if someone is looking for "pure" catenative verbs where the second verb has to be there, he won't find anything. In particular, every verb may be replaced by an equivalent noun. One may start (or stop) to read but he may start (or stop) the reading or the research project, too. He may want to eat but he may also want some food. To some extent, it's true even for quasi-verbs that are used to make tenses - has, had, would, will, ...

Comment: @LubošMotl then perhaps catenative is not the right word. I think of the word "must" in English. I don't know what linguists consider its function to be precisely, but we know that it can only be followed by another verb. My real question is about Mandarin, though. There seems to be many verbs that can ONLY be followed by other verbs, that don't seem "modal"

Comment: Not every one. "Hesitate" for example cannot take an NP object but can take a catenative complement.

Comment: @pixelearth There are quite a few catenative verbs that are intransitive; as I just said "hesitate" is but one of many.

Comment: OK, great, but it's still possible to say "he hesitated" without either an object or another verb, so it's not true that it "needs" another verb.

Comment: @pixelearth To be clear, are you looking for intransitive verbs whose catenative complement is obligatory?

Comment: @Luboš Motl Of course; you said that _every catenative verb may be a transitive verb_, and that's not so. "Hesitate" demonstrates that.

Comment: I don't think there are any verbs in English (and therefore no formal 'category') that cannot take an object and obligatorily require a catenative complement. What we're looking for here are intransitive verbs that **must** have a catenative complement to be grammatical. Apart from the auxiliaries, of course.

Comment: @BillJ That's a good question, I'll have to ask my teacher if the complement is required or can work similarly to "he hesitated".

Comment: @BillJ Maybe not in English, but that doesn't affect the existence of such verbs in general, as the OP mentioned, they do exist in Mandarin, so it doesn't matter for the question how such verbs may behave in English.

Comment: Also thanks for all the comments, I hope I haven't started a scuffle! I've learned a lot, and if I can remember how to say "catenative intransitive verb" tomorrow, I'm bound to impress at least myself! Lol.

Comment: @lemontree. it does, because that's what the OP is asking!

Comment: @pixelearth. Good luck!

Comment: @BillJ No, the question was whether there is a specific term for this kind of verbs and in that one comment you basically just said that there are no examples from English.

Comment: @lemontree Leave it alone now. The OP has 'signed off'.

Comment: Okay. Didn't mean to start a fight or so ;)

Comment: Also if anyone wants to make an answer saying this is basically a catenative intransitive verb, I'll "accept" it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41769/discussion-on-question-by-pixelearth-what-do-you-call-a-verb-that-requires-anoth).

Answer (score 1):

"Catena" is a good start, but a more specific term for this--since "catena," as far as I am aware, can refer to all sorts of strings, not just of verbs--is  **serial verb construction**.  ("**Verb serialization**" and "**verb stacking**" are other names for this phenomenon.)

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_verb_construction#Contrast_with_compound_verbs) on serial verb constructions specifically cites Mandarin as a language in which they are to be found. It adds this note:

> In Chinese, however, there is often no clear distinction between
>   serial verb phrases and prepositional phrases. The first three "verbs"
>   in the above sentence *("wǒ zuò fēijī cóng Shànghǎi dào Běijīng qù"/
>   "I sit aircraft depart Shanghai arrive Beijing travel"/
>   "I travel from Shanghai to Beijing by aircraft")* may alternatively be regarded as prepositions
>   (this applies particularly to words like cóng which do not normally
>   appear as independent verbs). Words used in that way in Chinese and in
>   some other languages are commonly referred to as **coverbs**.

As for the question of whether they exist in English, Wikipedia has this to say:

> Certain expressions resembling serial verb construction are found in
>   English (surviving from Early Modern English), such as let's go eat
>   and come live with me.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_verb) In such constructions, the second verb would
>   normally be regarded as a bare infinitive (and can generally be
>   replaced by a "full" infinitive by the insertion of to before it).

Cf. [compound verb/complex predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_verb), a related-but-different idea